# Has somebody work with GoogleCredentials?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-admin

At firebase **admin** release notes:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java

Initialization

FEATURE **FirebaseOptions** can now be initialized with **GoogleCredentials.**

http://google.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.7.1/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html

I don't understand the documentation or how to proceed. 
Can somebody share their knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are code samples at https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk

For example, to load a service account: `GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream);`, where inputStream is usually a `FileInputStream` to a service account json file.